# Call Recording using VOICE_CALL AudioSource is not working in Android Pie Version

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-development

I have a problem in recording a call I have made a service to get the call state. In TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK when the call is received. I am using following code to record the call

```
 rec = new MediaRecorder();
            rec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            rec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
            rec.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + sdf + "rec.aac");
            rec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            manager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                    System.out.println("incomingNumber : " + incomingNumber);
                    System.out.println("state : " + state);

                    if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state && rec == null) {
                        rec.stop();
                        rec.reset();
                        rec.release();
                        recordstarted = false;
                    } else if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                        try {
                            rec.prepare();
                            rec.start();
                            recordstarted = true;

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

            return START_STICKY;
        }
```

with the permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This code is working fine and creates the audio file but when I listen the audio file I can only listen my outgoing voice, caller voice is not recorded.

When I Use

`recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);`

Instead of

`recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);`

in above code, It throws an Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)

also Tried **AudioSource.CAMCORDER,AudioSource.DEFAULT** but it works same as **AudioSource.MIC**.
**AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION** also not supported.

**So How it will record a Call in Latest Android Version? Currently I am testing on Android 9 Version.**

Comment: In Android 9 & 10 you must do Audio recording in foreground. If you're doing this in background then it should not work

Comment: @MD Can you please refer me How I wiil do this On foreground? and What is the issue in background Recording? Have you try this on Latest Android Version?